# From website builder HTML content box, Filter text/names from a google spreadsheet using javascript

Tags: javascript, filter, full-text-search, spreadsheet

I am new in programming. I just recently created a simple search tool filtering names from a table and it works. Suddenly the number of characters are limited in go daddy website builder html content box. But I need to include more content. Now I used the google spreadsheet to handle more contents.I already included an iFrame to my code to view the spreadsheet. But I don't know how to filter the names from the spreadsheet using a javascript code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

Most of my codes came from other threads, and i just modified it for my needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<style>


body {

   background-image: url("http://www.sethnet.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/5485436-business-wallpaper.jpg");
   background-size: 1080px 800px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: fixed;

}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#myInput {

  background-image:url('https://previews.123rf.com/images/arhimicrostok/arhimicrostok1708/arhimicrostok170801660/84518390-icon-of-loupe-search-button-magnifying-glass-flat-design-style-.jpg');
  background-size: 32px 22px;
 background-position: 1%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 5px solid #ADD8E6;
  position: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left : 25% ;

}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<!-- Header -->

  <div class="w3-center">
    <h1> <br><br></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-center">
    <h1 class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white"><span class="w3-padding w3-black w3-opacity-min"><b>We</b></span> <span class="w3-pink w3-opacity-min w3-hide-small w3-text-White">Search</span></h1>
  </div>
</header>

<div>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for Names.." title="Type in a name">

</div>


<div class="w3-center" "w3-margin">

<p><br></p>

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/example" 
style="height:1000px;width:100%; 
border: 3px solid #ADD8E6;
transition:height 1.5s ease;
-webkit-transition:height 1.5s ease;
-moz-transition:height .25s ease; onload=access()">
</iframe>

</div>


  <div class="w3-center">
    <h1> <br><br><br></h1>
  </div>


<script>


window.onload = function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ContactsearchFX();
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', ContactsearchFX);
});

function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, Spreadsheet, tr, td, i;     
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  Spreadsheet = document.getElementByTagName("iframe");
  tr = Spreadsheet.rows;
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].cells[0];
    if (td) {
      tr[i].style.display = filter && td.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
        ? "" : "none";
    }
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some code you tried.

Comment: Hello @JSchirrmacher, here's my complete code. Bare with me, since i'm not really familiar in coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things which will not work.

1. There are a couple of JavaScript errors, which you see if you open the web console. Try to fix them first. One of them is the call of the function `getElementByTagName()` which doesn't exist. There *is* a function `getElementsByTagName()` (take notice of the 's') which returns a list of tags - you want the first one.
2. The iframe content doesn't contain much, which you see if you open the URL specified in the `src` attribute of your `<iframe>`, so you cannot find much of rows. But maybe this is just an example you provided instead of using a real spreadsheet.
3. But the iframe will not be loaded when your code tries to access it. It might help to call `ContactsearchFX()` just when something is typed in your text field - this depends on what exactly you want to do.
4. The  content is a html document itself, but it doesn't contain a data structure with rows directly. You need to use DOM functions (like `getElementsByTagName()` for example) to access the contents.

I hope this helps a little, but I fear it might not be sufficient to get some code snippets from around the internet to get an application running... I think you will need to get someone who is able to do this work for you unless you are willing to learn programming yourself.